# How to share node_modules between multiple docker containers in a monorepo, built with docker compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-modules, monorepo

I have a monorepo project like this:

```
root
--package.json
--node_modules
--packages
----packageA (frontend)
------node_modules
------package.json
------Dockerfile

----packageB (backend)
------node_modules
------package.json
------Dockerfile

----packageC (etc..)
------node_modules
------package.json
------Dockerfile
---- ....
```

Each of the packages has a Dockerfile, and each of these Dockerfiles contains a step where I instruct docker to "RUN yarn install", since every package in this repo is a JavaScript package. I also have a docker compose yml file, that references each of these separate docker files, and builds them. My issue is, since every Dockerfile has a yarn install inside of them, the compose build becomes incredibly slow (30-40m). This is expected, since it has to download, link etc the dependencies every time from scratch.

Now... I think there might be a way to speed this up, by taking the whole repo, running yarn install **once** and possibly even **outside of docker**, and than share the node_modules folder across every project.

The answers to these questions I'm not able to figure out:

- Why is there no tutorials, docs, etc about this? Does this mean I'm trying to do something that is conceptually wrong?
- How do people deal with node_modules in Docker compose orchestrated, multi container, monorepo projects?
- Maybe I should not even try to build the packages in different containers, just build them all in one container, than somehow export the binaries to different containers and run those separately?

What I've tried so far:

- Mounting my local node_modules folder, via volumes in the docker compose yml file, but this has failed because docker volume mount just won't mount folders starting with . (dot character). These folders are necessary for building the packages, they conatain things like "lerna.cmd" This is also an issue that I'm not able to understand, or find any bug reports/solutions. - again, **am I not even supposed to try to mount .bin folders from node_modules to a docker container, or is this a bug?**
- Caching the docker compose build in my CI/CD pipeline, so it's only dreadfully slow when I change something. This also failed, because the only solution I found was so slow when saving/loading the cache, the whole build was faster when I removed the caching altogether.

Please do comment if you think something needs more clarification, I know this is sort of vague, since it's hard to pinpoint the problem exactly when talking about such an abstract topic.

I'm using docker desktop on a Windows 10 machine. [**Docker version 20.10.21**, build baeda1f]